# What is meant by common terms in software company names?

Tags: word-usage

A set of terms occurs frequently in software company names. Some are pretty obvious like "-soft," "software," and "apps/applications." However, some are not so obvious (at least to me). What is the connotative/denotative meaning of these words when they occur in a software company name? What about a company would make it more/less likely to use one of these descriptors?

1. Designs
2. Dynamics
3. Solutions
4. Systems

Comment: They sometimes have some denotational value, but they are mostly just marketese, like the names of many companies in other fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [this](http://informatique.umons.ac.be/genlog/SE/SE-contents.html) page out for an even bigger glossary. And for your answer:

1. **Designs:** The phase in the software life-cycle that emphasises a logical solution, i.e. how the system fulfills the requirements. During object-oriented design, there is an emphasis on defining logical software objects that will ultimately be implemented in an object-oriented programming language. In this view, the design serves as a high level description of the source code, describing its key features and giving a blueprint of how the code is organised.

   Hence, a company might suggest that it is capable of (with other things) delivering high level description of the source code highlighting the key features.
2. **Dynamics:** I think the word would make sense if a company deals with dynamic solutions rather than static. E.g.: A company creating content management systems. or even MS Dynamics and other enterprise resource planning (ERP) and customer relationship management (CRM) software applications.
   E.g.: [Dynamic Software](http://www.dynamicssoftware.com)
3. **Solutions:** I guess anyone who provides an end-product(solution) would make sense. It can be area specific like *web solutions* or can even mean a wider deliverable like a whole system (CRM and ERP), etc. E.g.: [Opera Solutions](http://www.operasolutions.com/)
4. **Systems:** Using this word in a name would suggest a more hardware oriented solution like a company that would respond to specific network topology needs or even large scale data storage needs. E.g.: [Cisco Systems, Inc.](http://www.cisco.com/)

And of course, most names are coined to sound catchy or stand out, without even having to mean or relate anything. :)